# Change jQuery Validate errorPlacement on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, jquery-validate

I'm trying to change error messages on different devices, because, for example, on desktop, I have 6 inputs placed 3 in 3, in tablet placed 2 in 2 and in mobile placed 1 in 1 occupying 100%.

By design specifications, the messages must be shown together by block of inputs. For this reason, on the desktop, error messages should be displayed 3 in 3 after every 3 input.

[image: An example on desktop]

I have additional  to enter the error messages on each device.

```
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-3">
        <label for="promotional-code">Código promocional</label>
        <input id="promotional-code" name="promotional_code" type="text">
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
        <label for="first-name">Nombre</label>
        <input id="first-name" name="first_name" type="text">
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2 error-tablet-first"></div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-3 col-md-offset-0">
        <label for="last-name">Apellidos</label>
        <input id="last-name" name="last_name" type="text">
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2 error-desk-first"></div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-md-offset-2">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input id="email" name="email" type="email">
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2 error-tablet-second"></div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-2 col-md-offset-0">
        <label for="mobile-number">Teléfono móvil</label>
        <input id="mobile-number" name="mobile_number" type="number">
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <label for="service">Servicio</label>
        <select id="service" name="service">
            <option value="">Seleccionar servicio</option>
            <option value="visa">Reparaciones</option>
            <option value="presupuestos">Presupuestos</option>
            <option value="urgencias">Urgencias</option>
            <option value="seguros">Seguros</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2 error-tablet-third"></div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2 error-desk-second"></div>
```

For example, when it is desktop I put the first three messages in the tag ".error-desk-first"

The jQuery Validate call:

```
         $("#form").validate({
            ignore: null,
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                if (desktop) {
                    if (element.attr("name") == "promotional_code"
                        || element.attr("name") == "first_name"
                        || element.attr("name") == "last_name") {
                        error.appendTo('.error-desk-first');
                    }
                    else if (element.attr("name") == "email"
                        || element.attr("name") == "mobile_number"
                        || element.attr("name") == "service") {
                        error.appendTo('.error-desk-second');
                    }
                }
                else if (tablet) {
                    if (element.attr("name") == "promotional_code"
                        || element.attr("name") == "first_name") {
                        error.appendTo('.error-tablet-first');
                    }
                    else if (element.attr("name") == "email"
                            || element.attr("name") == "last_name") {
                        error.appendTo('.error-tablet-second');
                    }
                    else if (element.attr("name") == "mobile_number"
                            || element.attr("name") == "service") {
                        error.appendTo('.error-tablet-third');
                    }
                    else if (element.attr("name") == "privacy_politic"
                            || element.attr("name") == "not_notify") {
                        var next = element.next();
                        error.insertAfter(next);
                    }
                    else {
                        error.insertAfter(element);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            },
            rules: {
                promotional_code: "required",
                first_name: "required",
                last_name: "required",
                email: "required",
                mobile_number: "required",
                service: "required"
            },
            messages: {
                promotional_code: "Promotional code",
                first_name: "Firs name",
                last_name: "Last name",
                email: "Email",
                mobile_number: "Mobile number",
                service: "Service"
            }
```

When the document is ready, everything works. But when I try to get the error messages updated in the page resize event, I tried to destroy the validate and re-create it, but desktop to tablet, still displaying error messages on desktop .

I have also tried to call the validate again with the errorPlacement, but I also get nothing.

Any ideas? It only occurs to me that with javascript, on each device, retrieve all error messages, since it creates them with an attribute "id", and make an appendTo where I am interested.

Thank´s

Comment: Show where you define `tablet` and `desktop` variables.

Answer (score 0):

The whole problem with your approach is that once the error messages are "placed" in the layout, the plugin simply toggles their visibility; it does not re-"place" them in your new location.

> I have also tried to call the validate again with the errorPlacement, but I also get nothing.

You cannot call `.validate()` more than once on the page.  All subsequent calls are ignored.

> I tried to destroy the validate and re-create it, but desktop to tablet, still displaying error messages on desktop.

Destroying the validator first is the only way you can call `.validate()` again.  Doing this *after* the window has been resized seems like it should work.  However, you have not shown us this approach so it's impossible to say why this didn't work for you.

---

This whole idea of having custom JavaScript error placement based on screen size is overly complex.  There is no reason why you can't do this solely using CSS media queries.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, did not change position because when I did a `.destroy()` on the form the error messages that had already been shown does not destroy them, it only leaves them in `display:none`, therefore, when calling back to the Function `.validate()` and display error messages, did it in the same tag as the validator had previously created.

When the `.destroy()` is done, you must manually delete the error message tags.